# Inequality problem where $\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i^{-1}=2017^{-1}$.

Tags: inequality

If $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} k_i^{-1}=2017^{-1}$, find the minimum value of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} k_i$ when $n=2017$ and $n=2016$.

What I could do is just mere AM-HM inequality to get the case for $n=2017$ and the minimum value comes to be $2017$. But I don't think it's right as the equality case doesn't hold.

What are the correct solutions and do state the equality cases as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :**  Consider the product $$\Big ( k_1+k_2+k_3+ \dots k_n\Big)\Big(\frac{1}{k_1}+\frac{1}{k_2}+\frac{1}{k_3}+\dots \frac{1}{k_n} \Big)$$

Now apply AM-GM inequality in each pair of : $$\frac{k_i}{k_j}~ \text{and}~ \frac{k_j}{k_i}.$$

Comment: Thanks, I crossed 1k because of your upvote :) I am commenting so that I may know later where and when did I cross it.